# How to apply a computed class on button on page refresh?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I've created a menu to select different section of a report. In order to do so, buttons are created with v-for. The selected section is shown on the webpage when button is clicked.

I use the "flat" class from Vuetify to highlight (or not) the active section. For this, I checked if the button matches with the selected section shown => if not (not active), I use the "flat" class, if yes (active), I use the plain button.

The Vue Component

```
<v-btn
  v-for="section in this.$store.state.report"
  :key="section.sectionName"
  :flat="isSectionActive(section)"
  @click="selectSection(section)"
>
{{ section.sectionName }}
</v-btn>
```

The Vue Method

```
methods: {
  selectSection (section) {
    this.$store.commit('setSelectedSection', section)
  },
  isSectionActive (section) {
    return this.$store.state.selectedSection != section
  }
}
```

I've noticed that the check is not made anymore on page refresh (i.e. all buttons are considered as "not active") and I don't understand why.

Any ideas ?

Note that the vuex states are persisted in localstorage with "vuex-persistedstate" (i.e. the states are not lost on refresh).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try to compare not the `section`, but `section.sectionName`

Comment: @Styx Thank you very much, it works!!! However, I don't understand why... :-D

Comment: Because in Javascript two objects are equal if (and only if) they refer to the exact same object, and it seems that somewhere they are copied. Comparing their "key" properties is safer.